# Multiple karma.conf.js files after creating a new Angular project

Tags: angular

I am using Angular Cli 7.3.3 on Ubuntu 18.04

After doing a "ng new foo", I can find multiple karma.conf.js files under different directories under node_modules directory and under src directory, like below:

```
$ find . -name karma.conf.js
./node_modules/socket.io-parser/node_modules/debug/karma.conf.js
./node_modules/debug/karma.conf.js
./node_modules/karma-chrome-launcher/examples/simple/karma.conf.js
./node_modules/http-proxy-agent/node_modules/debug/karma.conf.js
./node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/debug/karma.conf.js
./node_modules/psl/karma.conf.js
./node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/debug/karma.conf.js
./node_modules/browserify-zlib/karma.conf.js
./node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/debug/karma.conf.js
./node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/debug/karma.conf.js
./src/karma.conf.js
```

What are the usages of the different karma.conf.js files under different ./node_modules/xxx directories?

When I need to configure Karma test (for example, to use headless Chrome, so I can use it in GitLab CI), which of the karma.conf.js should I edit? ./src/karma.conf.js?

What's the relationship between ./src/karma.conf.js and the other karma.conf.js files under ./node_modules?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should edit ./src/karma.conf.js. The other config files are for the tests of the third party libraries. As you can see, the other config files are mostly in /debug/ directories. This shows that they are used in the development/debugging of the package.